# A question about $L^p$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

If $1 \leqslant p_1,p_2 \leqslant \infty$ and $L^{p_1}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq L^{p_2}(\mathbb{R})$ ,prove that $p_1=p_2$

Can some one give me a hint to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @tchao:  I was replying to your Comment.  It is often more difficult to give a "hint" rather than a full answer that meets the goal of Math.SE for content, useful to Readers beyond the OP.  Edit your answer to include the specific contradiction assuming $p_1 \neq p_2$ and I will vote to undelete.

Comment: I found two counterexamples to derive a contradiction.Let $p_1>p_2$ ,then $p_1/p_2>1$.I took the function $f=\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}1/ \sqrt[p_2]{x}$ We can see that $f \in L_{p_1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \notin  L_{p_2}(\mathbb{R})$ which is a contradiction because of the set inclusion in hypothesis.Now if $p_2>p_1$ then i took the $g=\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1]}1/ \sqrt[p_2]{x+1}$.We can see that $g \in  L_{p_1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $g \notin L_{p_2}(\mathbb{R})$